How to attach a custom header to /api/auth/session GET request in SessionProvider?
I am trying to use SessionProvider from next-auth like so:
"use client";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

export function MySessionProvider({ children, session }) {
    return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
            {children}
        </SessionProvider>
    );
};

Then I use it in the main layout.
Behind the scenes SessionProvider fires GET request to /api/auth/session.
I can't find in documentation how can I tune the behavior of such request from client-side.
I really need to attach an additional HTTP header to that request. I am trying to send an actual device fingerprint for custom checks in my sessions API.

Well, I decided just to write my own context provider instead of SessionProvider:
"use client";
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useFetchGet } from "@hooks/frontendRequests";
import projectPaths from "@utils/projectPaths";

const UserContext = createContext("");

export function UserContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const fetchResult = useFetchGet(projectPaths.API_USERS + "/self");


    useEffect(() => {
        if (fetchResult.user) {
            setUser(fetchResult.user);
        }
    }, [fetchResult]);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
}

export function useUserContext() {
    const context = useContext(UserContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error("useUserContext must be used within UserContextProvider.");
    }
    return context;
}

useFetchGet sets up all necessary headers, and my custom API endpoint not just checks the session, but also returns useful payload in case of success.
If something is wrong with the session, the server will return Error 401, and my front-end useFetchGet function will take care of it, by re-routing on the client side.
